# Fluent NHibernate mapping a class where the Id is a reference to another class

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, fluent

I am trying to use fluent nHibernate to map a class that only exists as a container for other classes, and doesn't have an Id of its own. But I want the Id of the class to be a different class. That really doesn't make sense, it might be easier to explain with an example data structure.

```
abstract QueryBuilder
{
  public IEnumerable<string> Category1Keys {get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<int> Category2Ids {get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<int> Category3Ids {get; set;}
}

Set
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public SetQueryBuilder QueryBuilder{get; set;}
}

SetQueryBuilder : QueryBuilder
{
}

News
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public NewsQueryBuilder QueryBuilder{get; set;}
}

NewsQueryBuilder : QueryBuilder
{
}
```

Now the QueryBuilder is the name is a concept that we use to map various (unrelated) items to the same categories. So things that might use QueryBuidler are News, Pages, Permissions.

Becuase all the various items that use QueryBuilder map that relationship in the same way, and ocasionally we actually use the paramters from one type of QueryBuilder as a the select criteriea for another type of QueryBuilder (ie if news has QB of A, get all the Sets that match the same criteria), I want to have a abstract QueryBuilder class, and then extend it for all the things that have mappings to all the categories.

Here is an example of the Set DB for query builder. There isn't an actual item in the DB for QueryBuilder - its composed of all the info from the category class join tables.

```
f_set
{
  set_id (PK, int)
  name (varchar)
}

f_set_cat1
{
  set_id (PK, FK, int)
  cat1_key (PK, FK, char(3))
}

f_set_cat2
{
  set_id (PK, FK, int)
  cat2_id (PK, FK, int)
}

f_set_cat3
{
  set_id (PK, FK, int)
  cat3_id (PK, FK, int)
}
```

My problem is how to map each instance of the QueryBuilder class in nHibernate, as it doesnt' have a real key or table entry, I would like to say that the Id is a reference to the Set that all the category mappings use.

Here are my fluent mappings so far:

```
SetMapping : ClassMap<Set>
{
  public SetMapping()
  {
    Schema("cam");
    Table("f_set");
    Id(x => x.Id, "f_set_id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(x => x.Name, "name").Not.Nullable();
    HasOne<SetQueryBuilder>(x => x.QueryBuilder);
  }
}

SetQueryBuilderMapping : ClassMap<SetQueryBuilder>
{
  public SetQueryBuilderMapping()
  {
    References(x => x.Set, "set_id");
    HasMany(x => x.Category1Keys).Table("f_set_cat1").Element("cat1_key").KeyColumn("set_id");
    HasMany(x => x.Category2Ids).Table("f_set_cat2").Element("cat2_id").KeyColumn("set_id");
    HasMany(x => x.Category2Ids).Table("f_set_cat3").Element("cat3_id").KeyColumn("set_id");
  }
}
```

Any help with the final step of the mapping would be hugely appreciated
Thanks
Saan

FURTHER INVESTIGATION
Ok I have done a bit mroe investigating on this and have foudn that combining the two classes works fine if I do this:

```
CLASS:
Set
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  //public SetQueryBuilder QueryBuilder{get; set;}

  public IEnumerable<string> Category1Keys {get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<int> Category2Ids {get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<int> Category3Ids {get; set;}
}

MAPPING
SetMapping : ClassMap<Set>
{
  public SetMapping()
  {
    Schema("cam");
    Table("f_set");
    Id(x => x.Id, "f_set_id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(x => x.Name, "name").Not.Nullable();
    //HasOne<SetQueryBuilder>(x => x.QueryBuilder);

    HasMany(x => x.Category1Keys).Table("f_set_cat1").Element("cat1_key").KeyColumn("set_id");
    HasMany(x => x.Category2Ids).Table("f_set_cat2").Element("cat2_id").KeyColumn("set_id");
    HasMany(x => x.Category2Ids).Table("f_set_cat3").Element("cat3_id").KeyColumn("set_id");
  }
}
```

When doing nHibernate mappings this makes perfect sense, but I would really like to have all the category mappings in the separate SetQueryBuilder class.

Thanks again for any help
Saan

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for subclassing strategy. Take a look at this http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance

You probably want to follow a table per class with table per subclass strategy imo.

Comment: Hi Yads. Thanks for the response, but I'm not sure the sub class mappings apply here, while QueryBuilder is a abstract class, there isn't really a sub class for it to extend. And there defiantley isn't any base class in the DB for it to extend. Its just a collection of join tables that conceptually belong together. The actual error I'm getting is "The entity 'GcmQueryBuilder' doesn't have an Id mapped. Use the Id method to map your identity property. For example: Id(x => x.Id).". The Id of the table is the Id of the Set or News table.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not understanding what you mean. Would it be possible for you to give me a bit more detail on the solution you think will work. Sorry, I'm still new to nHibernate. Thanks, Saan

Comment: @Saan, if it's really a query builder it should not be mapped as an nhibernate entity. Your categories, (if they're indeed associated with the set,) should be associated with the set entity. Your query builder should actually help with building a query. So I'm not sure your architecture makes any sense in the context of NHibernate.

Comment: Yeah we finally decided that too. We went with making the QueryBuilder an Interface so we can still pass it to other things that know about QueryBuilders, and then the category details are then in the Set. Thanks heaps for your help.